# Each_pair analog for array (zipping 2 arrays)

Tags: ruby, arrays

There is `each_pair` method allows getting pairs of hash on every loop iteration:

```
{ 1 => "a", 2 => "b" }.each_pair do |key, value|
   # do something with #{key} and #{value}
end
```

How can index of current array element could be known on every loop iteration?

```
array.each do |element|
  # what is element index in array?
end
```

There is a boring solution using some incrementing iterator. But that iterator
should be assigned before the loop and should be manually incremented on every
iteration. It's obviously boring.

It will be great if there is a some way to zip some array with `1..` array and
get array of tuples like `["b", "d", "e"] → [(1,"b"), (2,"d"), (3,"e")] and
than pattern matched each element of the pair in`| |` statement.

So, finally, what I am looking for is some function `f`, that:

```
f(["a"]) do |index, element|
  # index == 1, element == "a"
end
```

Comment: The index of Array is zero-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop over an array and get the current index by using [Enumerable::each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming that you want an array consisting of sub-arrays with the originall arrays index and value?

```
a= ["b", "d", "e"]
a.enum_with_index.map {|ind, val| [ind, val]
=> [[0, "b"], [1, "d"], [2, "e"]]
```

Comment: Actually, he says he's looking for a method that gives him the loop index and the element, which is precisely what `each_with_index` does. Your answer is just zipping the array with its indexes. The resulting array could then kinda be iterated over like what he's looking for, but not exactly. If that zipped array is what's desired, `a.zip(1..a.length)` would do it.